# Execute for loop like a promise

Tags: javascript, velo

The records that I getting with wixData.query() inside a for loop are either not being added to the array or (What I think is more likely) my console.log() is being executed before the records have been assigned to the array.

Before my for loop executes, I grab the record ids for all the records that I want from a master list. Once they are all found, a function is called that will find all of the matching records in two other databases. I was thinking that Promises might be the way to go however, they do not appear to allow for parameters to be passed to them.

```
export function exportPart(event) {

    // Calls a function that performs all necessary actions. This needs to be done once for three different
    // databases so to simplify it, a function call is made passing in the string for the database desired.

    wixData.query("master_participant_data")
        .eq("cs_data", true)
        .eq("permission_granted", true)
        .eq("maze_map_completed", true)
        .eq("submitted", false)
        .find()
        .then((records) => {
            if (records.items.length > 0) {
                let numOfRecords = records.items.length
                var customer_ids = []
                for (var i = 0; i < numOfRecords; i++) {
                    customer_ids.push(records.items[i]._id)
                }
                processBatch("Student_Data", customer_ids)
                processBatch("7Cs_Data", customer_ids)
            }
        })
}

// Will process records and make api requests
export function processBatch(collection, recordIDs) {
    var status = "Beginning Export...\nGrabbing new records...\n"
    $w('#exportStatus').value = status

    var records = []

    for (var i = 0; i < recordIDs.length; i++) {
        wixData.query(collection)
            .eq("customer_id", recordIDs[i])
            .find()
            .then((result) => {
                records.push(result.items[0])
                console.log("These are the results of query: " + JSON.stringify(result.items[0]))
            })
    }
    console.log("Located records: " + records)
}
```

What I am looking for is something like a Promise that I can execute to ensure that the for loop executes fully (to get all matching records else where) before running any more code so console.log("Located records: " + records) will display records instead of being empty.

Comment: well, you have a Promise  by the look of it ... or at least a *then-able* ... so, half the problem is solved already - the other half ... https://pastebin.com/uG7CZGKb

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I figured it was something that I was just not aware of/new how to correctly use aka await/async and map().